# Is there any way to use compile time variables on a .html file using MsBuild?

Tags: msbuild, cordova, continuous-integration

I have a PhoneGap project that use custom MSBuild scripts running in TeamCity as a CI build.
What I want to add now is zip and send the project files with the PhoneGap REST API on each check-in.
But before sending the files I need to make a few changes inside the head node of the index.html since there are URIs to a service that differs from DEBUG, TEST, RELEASE environments.

Is there any way I could use something like #ifdef with build properties on a .html file or is there perhaps an even better way of solving this scenario using MsBuild/TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup custom tokens (like "*##replace this##*") and then simply update HTML content using TeamCity PowerShell build step.

Comment: As I specified I'm doing this using a MsBuild script file but I guess I could do that same parsing of the HTML and replace stuff with MsBuild.
It just doesn't seem that "clean" doing string replacements..
Any other ideas?